# Can I use an API such as chef to automatically create, name and set passwords to multiple servers?

Tags: api, automation, passwords, nodes, rackspace

I am new to this so forgive me for not understanding the lingo.

I have been using rackspace cloud control panel to build multiple virtual servers, i use them for maybe a couple of hours then i delete them.  I need these servers to all have specific and unique names such as: "server1, server2, server3, etc." I also need them to have a specific password unlike the randomly generated password that is assigned by default.

I have been creating each individual server manually (based on an image that's set up) then I have to go back and reset the password andreboot all of them. Doing each one manually is a bit time consuming and I'm sure there is an easier way.  Please help me figure this out.

I've been doing some searching but I haven't found anything too relevant to my problem on top of that I'm not too familiar with programming and such.

Basically what I'm looking to do is automatically create these servers with their appropriate names and passwords already built in from the start.  I'm not sure if some sort of "API" is the answer, or if there's some sort of script that can be written, or both.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

thanks,

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, are you well versed on any programming language?

Comment: Hello, I am not, but I am interested in learning.

Comment: Chris, while it would be very difficult to teach programming in any practical amount of time, we could provide an alternative solution that, while not fully automated, it will certainly alleviate some of the burden and the need to go through the Control Panel as often.To that end, what OS you work on? What OS are the cloud servers you're spinning up?

Comment: OK, Thanks. I am using windows 8 and the servers are running windows server 2008.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, most provisioning libraries out there run on linux/Mac OSX. Given that both your machine and the servers you are working with are Windows, not sure what can be done to automate things, unfortunately. I will do some research and see if I can find out if it's possible, but can't promise anything at this point.